# What is the use of task in MemoryStream ReadAsync?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Why the [`MemoryStream.ReadAsync`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,2142088b3533a169) is using task, even though the code does't have any `async` or `await`. I am sure that using `async` here won't give any performance improvement because it is not an I/O operation, it is an in-memory operation.

It is look like there are using some caching but they still calling the synchronous read method

```
Read(buffer, offset, count)
```

Then what is the use of the task here?

Comment: The base class defines it with this signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is the use of the task here?

The [base `Stream` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) predated the [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap). When asynchronous methods were added to the BCL, streams were an obvious choice (asynchronous code is ideal for I/O operations). So, it was decided to add `ReadAsync` (and friends) to the base `Stream` type.

However, backwards compatibility (as always) must be a priority. So, the base `Stream` class has to include an implementation; it can't be `abstract`. The base `Stream` class will either [wrap the `BeginRead`/`EndRead` methods](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L432) (if the derived type implements the [APM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm)), or just [call `Read` on a thread pool thread](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L548).

`MemoryStream` - since it knows it's just dealing with a memory buffer - [overrides this default thread pool behavior to just be synchronous](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs#L394).

Answer (score 1):

It states for itself:

```
[HostProtection(ExternalThreading = true)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public override Task<int> ReadAsync
```

This method is an `override` for the base `public virtual Task<int> ReadAsync` method from [`Stream`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,e224b4bec8748849) class. Please note that this override logic is introduced **only** in case of `FEATURE_ASYNC_IO` variable defined:

```
#if FEATURE_ASYNC_IO
```

This is a new way to implement the `async` approach, via `Task`-based methods. It will return the completed task, which, while being `await`ed, will **not** switch the context and will execute synchronously.

In other case it will use a default implementation, which simply calls the [`BeginEndReadAsync`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,81408d129d1e9739,references) - the old way to provide asynchronous model, with `BeginRead`/`EndRead` method pair with callback model.